How to connect esp01 to SocketIO server?
I'm trying to connect my esp8266 to a SocketIO server, I can connect to WiFi but the only status i get from the socket is the DISCONNECTED one.
This is the code I have so far:
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>

// Wi-Fi credentials
const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "password";

WebSocketsClient webSocket;

void webSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {
  switch(type) {
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.printf("[WSc] Disconnected!\n");
      break;
    case WStype_CONNECTED:
      Serial.printf("[WSc] Connected to url: %s\n", payload);
      webSocket.sendTXT("Connected");
      break;
    case WStype_TEXT:
      Serial.printf("[WSc] get text: %s\n", payload);
      break;
    case WStype_BIN:
      Serial.printf("[WSc] get binary length: %u\n", length);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Wi-Fi config
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi ..");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print('.');
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("\nConnected to WiFi");

  // websocket config
  webSocket.begin("https://switch-backend-2trd.onrender.com/switch", 443, "/socket.io");
  webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
  webSocket.setReconnectInterval(2500);
}

void loop() {
  webSocket.loop();
}

I tried to run this code with begin, beginSSL and nothing seemed to work. If I input that same connection info in postman, it works fine, but not here.
I was expecting to get a connection and be able to send, listen to events from this server.

socket.io != Websockets. They use Websockets as transport, but implment its own protocol on top of it. Implement the protocol (https://socket.io/docs/v4/socket-io-protocol/) or use plain websockets.
